# How to rename a folder via csom c# in SharePoint List?

Tags: development, client-object-model, folder

How can I rename a folder in a list via CSOM (c#).

I tried it with:

```
var folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderRelativeUrl);
ctx.Load(folder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var folderItem = folder.ListItemAllFields;
folderItem["Title"] = newTitle;
folderItem["FileLeafRef"] = newTitle;
folderItem.Update();
ctx.Load(folder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

and

```
ListItem folder = getFolderViaCaml();
folder["Name"] = newTitle;
folder["FileLeafRef"] = newTitle;
folder.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

but I just get the following exception

> Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are
>   trying to update may be read only.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ca23043-5ad3-4ef9-8aba-d97a3bfc190b/renamemove-folder-including-files-and-subfoders-using-client-api?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the folder item. I don't think you can get the item directly from folder, but you can get it from the list.

Example:

```
public static void Rename(ClientContext ctx, List list, String oldName, String newName)
{
    const string queryFormat =
        "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where>" +
        "<Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq>" +
        "</Where></Query></View>";
    var items = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery
    {
        ViewXml = string.Format(queryFormat, oldName)
    });
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    items.ToList().ForEach(item =>
    {
        item["FileLeafRef"] = newName;
        item.Update();
    });
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most probably in the first example the error occurs due to the line shown below:

```
folderItem.Update();
ctx.Load(folder); //<-loading of folder that has been moved! 
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Depending on the SharePoint version you could consider the following examples for renaming of folder.

**SharePoint 2010**

```
 public static class FolderExtensions
 {
    public static void RenameFolder(this Folder folder,string name)
    {
        var ctx = folder.Context;
        var folderItem = folder.ListItemAllFields;
        folderItem["Title"] = name;
        folderItem["FileLeafRef"] = name;
        folderItem.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }

}
```

Usage

```
 var folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderRelativeUrl);
 folder.RenameFolder("Archive 2010");
```

**SharePoint 2013**

Using [Folder.MoveTo method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.moveto.aspx):

```
var folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(sourceFolderRelativeUrl);            
folder.MoveTo(targetFolderRelativeUrl);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```